# Linear searching for a target

Tags: c#, arrays, linear-search

As part of a coding challenge in my class, we have to produce code to provide for 10 different tasks.

In this task, my goal is to make a linear search algorithm that searches for a particular item in an array, and displays its position(s) if found.

This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Linearsearch2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new int[] { 1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99 }; //Sets up the array

            var targetvalue = 77; //Establishes what number the search will attempt to find.
            var targetpos = -1; //Establishes the position in the array of the target.
            var targetnumber = 0; //Establishes the counter for the number of times the target appears.
            bool found = false; //Decides wether to change the number or use a counter method.

            var foundpositions = new int[] { }; //Establishes an array which will hold the positions of located items

            for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (found == true && array[i] == targetvalue)
                {
                    targetnumber = targetnumber + 1;
                }

                if (found == false && array[i] == targetvalue) //If the target value has not been found yet
                {
                    foundpositions.Add(i); //This is the line i need help with. I dont know how to add a value to an array properly.
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (targetpos != -1){ //If the target number was found
                Console.WriteLine("The number " + targetvalue + " appeared " + targetnumber + " times, at positions " + foundpositions + "."); // Prints the final outcome.
            }
            else //If the target number was not found
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number " + targetvalue + " did not appear in this array."); // Prints the final outcome.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem i need help with is with line 31, with
foundpositions.Add(i);**

I do not know the line to properly add values to an array, and this is what seems to be causing the problem.
(In this line, i am attempting to add the current position of the search to an array that will be displayed later)

Thanks for the help. Also, if there any other obvious, glaring errors, pointing them out to would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you are checking to see if the target is found? This seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem i need help with is with line 31, with
>   foundpositions.Add(i);

Arrays are **not** dynamic and they don't have an `add()` method. you could use a `List` instead.

replace this:

```
var foundpositions = new int[] { };
```

with this:

```
var foundpositions = new List<int>();
```

also, you don't seem to have done anything with this declared variable:

```
var targetpos = -1;
```

hence control will **never** go inside this `if` block:

```
if (targetpos != -1){ //If the target number was found
      Console.WriteLine("The number " + targetvalue + " appeared " + targetnumber + " times, at positions " + foundpositions + "."); // Prints the final outcome.
}
```

> in this task, my goal is to make a linear search algorithm that
>   searches for a particular item in an array, and displays its
>   position(s) if found.

as your code currently looks, there seems to be several errors. However, the example below will help you get started:

```
public static int LinearSearch(int[] items, int target)
{
       if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("argument items has null reference");
       if (items.Length == 0) return -1; // return -1 if the item is not found
       for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            if (items[i] == target) return i;
       return -1; // return -1 if the item is not found
}
```

then simply call the `LinearSearch` within the `main` method passing in the required data and you're good to go.

don't forget to assign the returned value from `LinearSearch` into a variable or simply print it to console.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure WHY you are checking if the target numbers are found. If you want to get the indexes in the array of all the ints that equal the target int, then you could simply loop through the array and put the matches into a List of ints then return this list.

The count of this returned list will tell you how many matched the target and the list would contain the indexes of those matches. There does not appear to be any reason to check if the target was found while looping through the array. If the returned list is empty, then the target was not found. The code below used this approach. I hope I am not missing something.

```
private static void FindTargets() {
  var array = new int[] { 1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99, 1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99 }; //Sets up the array
  int target = 77;
  List<int> foundTargets = GetPositions(target, array);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("There are " + foundTargets.Count + " int(s) that match " + target + Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("The array indexs for the target ints " + target + " are: ");
  int count = 0;
  foreach (int curInt in foundTargets) {
    sb.Append(curInt);
    if (count < foundTargets.Count - 1)
      sb.Append(", ");
    count++;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

private static List<int> GetPositions(int target, int[] intArray) {
  List<int> foundTargets = new List<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++) {
    if (intArray[i] == target) {
      foundTargets.Add(i);
    }
  }
  return foundTargets;
}
```